# how do I solve the 'src/bootloader/boot.asm:324: error: TIMES value -17 is negative' error?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, nasm, boot

```
org 0x7C00
bits 16

%define ENDL 0x0D, 0x0A

;
; FAT12 header
; 
jmp short start
nop

bdb_oem:                    db 'MSWIN4.1'           ; 8 bytes
bdb_bytes_per_sector:       dw 512
bdb_sectors_per_cluster:    db 1
bdb_reserved_sectors:       dw 1
bdb_fat_count:              db 2
bdb_dir_entries_count:      dw 0x0e0
bdb_total_sectors:          dw 2880                 ; 2880 * 512 = 1.44MB
bdb_media_descriptor_type:  db 0F0h                 ; F0 = 3.5" floppy disk
bdb_sectors_per_fat:        dw 9                    ; 9 sectors/fat
bdb_sectors_per_track:      dw 18
bdb_heads:                  dw 2
bdb_hidden_sectors:         dd 0
bdb_large_sector_count:     dd 0

; extended boot record
ebr_drive_number:           db 0                    ; 0x00 floppy, 0x80 hdd, useless
                            db 0                    ; reserved
ebr_signature:              db 29h
ebr_volume_id:              db 12h, 34h, 56h, 78h   ; serial number, value doesn't matter
ebr_volume_label:           db 'GARB OS'        ; 11 bytes, padded with spaces
ebr_system_id:              db 'FAT12   '           ; 8 bytes


start:
    mov ax, 0
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x7C00

    push es
    push word .after
    retf
.after:

    mov [ebr_drive_number], dl

    ; shows messages
    mov si, msg_loading
    call puts
    mov si, welcome
    call puts

    push es
    mov ah, 0x08
    int 0x13
    jc floppy_error
    pop es

    mov cl, 0x3F
    xor ch, ch
    mov [bdb_sectors_per_track], cx

    inc dh
    mov [bdb_heads], dh

    mov ax, [bdb_sectors_per_track]
    mov bl, [bdb_sectors_per_track]
    xor bh, bh
    mul bx
    add ax, [bdb_reserved_sectors]
    push ax

    mov ax, [bdb_sectors_per_fat]
    shl ax, 5
    xor dx, dx
    div word [bdb_bytes_per_sector]

    test dx, dx
    jz .root_dir_after
    inc ax

.root_dir_after:
    mov cl, al
    pop ax
    mov dl, [ebr_drive_number]
    mov bx, buffer
    call disk_read

    ; look for kernel.bin
    xor bx, bx
    mov di, buffer

.search_kernel:
    mov si, file_kernel_bin
    mov cx, 11
    push di
    repe cmpsb
    pop di
    je .found_kernel

    add di, 32
    inc bx
    cmp bx, [bdb_dir_entries_count]
    jl .search_kernel

    jmp kernel_not_found_error

.found_kernel:
    mov ax, [di + 26]
    mov [kernel_cluster], ax

    mov ax, [bdb_reserved_sectors]
    mov bx, buffer
    mov cl, [bdb_sectors_per_fat]
    mov dl, [ebr_drive_number]
    call disk_read

    mov bx, KERNEL_LOAD_SEGMENT
    mov es, bx
    mov bx, KERNEL_LOAD_OFFSET

.load_kernel_loop:
    mov ax, [kernel_cluster]
    mov ax, 31

    mov cl, 1
    mov dl, [ebr_drive_number]
    call disk_read

    add bx, [bdb_bytes_per_sector]

    mov ax, [kernel_cluster]
    mov cx, 3
    mul cx
    mov cx, 2
    div cx

    mov si, buffer
    add si, ax
    mov ax, [ds:si]

    or dx, dx
    jz .even 

.odd:
    shr ax, 4
    jmp .next_cluster_after

.even:
    and ax, 0x0FFF

.next_cluster_after:
    cmp ax, 0x0FF8                      ; end of chain
    jae .read_finish

    mov [kernel_cluster], ax
    jmp .load_kernel_loop
    jmp wait_key_and_reboot

.read_finish:
    mov dl, [ebr_drive_number]          ; boot device in dl

    mov ax, KERNEL_LOAD_SEGMENT         ; set segment registers
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    jmp KERNEL_LOAD_SEGMENT:KERNEL_LOAD_OFFSET

    jmp wait_key_and_reboot

    cli
    hlt
;
; error handling
;
floppy_error:
    mov si, msg_read_failed
    call puts
    jmp wait_key_and_reboot

kernel_not_found_error:
    mov si, msg_kernel_not_found
    call puts
    jmp wait_key_and_reboot

wait_key_and_reboot:
    mov ah, 0
    int 0x16
    jmp 0FFFFh:0
.halt:
    cli
    hlt

;
; Prints a string to the screen
; Params:
;   - ds:si points to string
;
puts:
    ; save registers we will modify
    push si
    push ax
    push bx

.loop:
    lodsb               ; loads next character in al
    or al, al           ; verify if next character is null?
    jz .done

    mov ah, 0x0E        ; call bios interrupt
    mov bh, 0           ; set page number to 0
    int 0x10

    jmp .loop

.done:
    pop bx
    pop ax
    pop si    
    ret

;
; Disk routines
;

; Converts an LBA address to a CHS address
; Parameters:
;   - ax: LBA address
; Returns:
;   - cx [bits 0-5]: sector number
;   - cx [bits 6-15]: cylinder
;   - dh: head
;

lba_to_chs:

    push ax
    push dx

    xor dx, dx                          ; dx = 0
    div word [bdb_sectors_per_track]    ; ax = LBA / SectorsPerTrack
                                        ; dx = LBA % SectorsPerTrack

    inc dx                              ; dx = (LBA % SectorsPerTrack + 1) = sector
    mov cx, dx                          ; cx = sector

    xor dx, dx                          ; dx = 0
    div word [bdb_heads]                ; ax = (LBA / SectorsPerTrack) / Heads = cylinder
                                        ; dx = (LBA / SectorsPerTrack) % Heads = head
    mov dh, dl                          ; dh = head
    mov ch, al                          ; ch = cylinder (lower 8 bits)
    shl ah, 6
    or cl, ah                           ; put upper 2 bits of cylinder in CL

    pop ax
    mov dl, al                          ; restore DL
    pop ax
    ret


disk_read:
    push ax                             ; save registers we will modify
    push bx
    push cx
    push dx
    push di

    push cx
    call lba_to_chs
    pop ax
    mov ah, 0x02
    mov di, 3

.retry:
    pusha
    stc
    int 0x13
    jnc .done

    popa
    call disk_reset

    dec di
    test di, di
    jnz .retry

.fail:
    jmp floppy_error

.done:
    popa

    pop di
    pop dx
    pop cx
    pop bx
    pop ax                             ; restore registers modified
    ret

disk_reset:
    pusha
    mov ah, 0
    stc
    int 13h
    jc floppy_error
    popa
    ret



msg_loading:db "Loading.....", ENDL, 0
welcome: db "Welcome to GARB OS", ENDL, 0
msg_read_failed: db "Read from disk failed", ENDL, 0
file_kernel_bin: db "KERNEL  BIN"
msg_kernel_not_found: db "NO KERNEL WAS FOUND", ENDL, 0
kernel_cluster: dw 0

KERNEL_LOAD_SEGMENT     equ 0x2000
KERNEL_LOAD_OFFSET      equ 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55

buffer:
```

How do I solve the 'src/bootloader/boot.asm:324: error: TIMES value -17 is negative' error? I am building an OS and I don't know how to solve this error as I am new assembly.

I am following a tutorial and the code is the exact same. I thought `times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0` was the standard as it fills 512 bytes with 0s.

The guy in the tutorial is not having any problems and no one is talking about it in the comments. I am using this Makefile to compile the code:

```
ASM=nasm
CC=gcc
TOOLS_DIR=tools
SRC_DIR=src
BUILD_DIR=build

.PHONY: all floppy_image kernel bootloader clean always tools_fat

all: floppy_image tools_fat
#
# Floppy image
#
floppy_image: $(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img

$(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img: bootloader kernel
    dd if=/dev/zero of=$(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img bs=512 count=2880
    mkfs.fat -F 12 -n "GBOS" $(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img
    dd if=$(BUILD_DIR)/bootloader.bin of=$(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img conv=notrunc
    #mcopy -i $(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img $(BUILD_DIR)/stage2.bin "::stage2.bin"
    mcopy -i $(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.bin "::kernel.bin"
    mcopy -i $(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img test.txt "::test.txt"

#
# Bootloader
#
bootloader: $(BUILD_DIR)/bootloader.bin

$(BUILD_DIR)/bootloader.bin: always
    $(ASM) $(SRC_DIR)/bootloader/boot.asm -f bin -o $(BUILD_DIR)/bootloader.bin

#
# Kernel
#
kernel: $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.bin

$(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.bin: always
    $(ASM) $(SRC_DIR)/kernel/main.asm -f bin -o $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.bin

#
# Tools
#
tools_fat: $(BUILD_DIR)/tools/fat
$(BUILD_DIR)/tools/fat: always $(TOOLS_DIR)/fat/fat.c
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)/tools
    $(CC) -g -o $(BUILD_DIR)/tools/fat $(TOOLS_DIR)/fat/fat.c

#
# Always
#
always:
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)

#
# Clean
#
clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)/*
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You have too much shit in your bootloader and its exceeding the 510 bytes available for it.  You need to remove some of the code so it fits.

Comment: This error indicates that the number calculated for the `times` directive is negative. That happens if your program image (output of assembling) is already past the origin plus 510 bytes. The only way to solve this is to put fewer messages and/or less code into your sector loader. (If you want to look at a more advanced example you may consider [my bootloaders](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldosboot).)

Comment: @fuz thank you. I will remove all the comments and see if it fits.

Comment: @descartes Comments do not generate code.  Removing comments will achieve nothing.  You have to reduce the amount of code and data in the boot sector.  Alternatively, split the boot sector into multiple bits and load the remaining parts from RAM in the beginning.

Comment: @fuz well that was silly of me. It works now I copy pasted the code from github.